# Macedonia Entry with EU-permanent resident card?

Tags: visas, macedonia

Can i enter Macedonia with a valid EU permanent resident card and a valid Passport? I have heard so much controversy that it is not possible and both possible without a problem?

Comment: Yes you can. Residence cards that aren't permanent do not qualify, which may be the source of the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Republic of Macedonia Ministry of Foreign Affairs](http://www.mfa.gov.mk/index.php/en/) page on [Entry in the Republic of Macedonia for Schengen Visa Holders](http://Entry%20in%20the%20Republic%20of%20Macedonia%20for%20Schengen%20Visa%20Holders):

> Entry in the Republic of Macedonia for Schengen Visa Holders
>
> Citizens of the following countries are not required to have entry visa for the Republic of Macedonia:
>
> 1. EU member countries and signatories of the Schengen Agreement
>
>    have the right to enter the Republic of Macedonia with a valid ID card.
> 2. **Third countries with permanent stay in an EU member country or signatory country of the Schengen Agreement**
>
>    may stay in the Republic of Macedonia for up to 15 (fifteen) days upon every entry to the territory of the Republic of Macedonia, and the total amount of the subsequent stays in the Republic of Macedonia must not be longer than 3 (three) months within a six-months period, starting from the date of the first entry.
> 3. Third countries with multiple entry short stay Schengen visa type C valid at least 5 (five) days beyond the intended stay in the Republic of Macedonia.
>
>    may stay in the Republic of Macedonia for up to 15 (fifteen) days upon every entry to the territory of the Republic of Macedonia, and the total amount of the subsequent stays in the Republic of Macedonia must not be longer than 3 (three) months within a six-months period, starting from the date of the first entry.

I have highlighted the part that is relevant to you. You state that you are a holder of a permanent resident card and have a valid passport (from your own country of citizenship.) If you were a citizen of a Schengen signatory country you would not need a permanent resident card, therefore I can safely assume you are a citizen of a "third country." In this case, bullet 2 applies to you.

Since you are a citizen of a third country, with a permanent stay in an EU member country (or signatory country of the Schengen Agreement), you may stay in Macedonia for up to 15 days. You will be required to leave Macedonia at the end of that period. You may also revisit as often as you like, in 15 day increments, so long as your total visit time is not longer than 3 months in any 6 month period.